# iTextSharp: change the order of objects in existing PDF

Tags: itext

I'm dealing with a corporate report generating system that generates documents with stamps and signatures.

The sad thing is that the system is not able to place images below existing text and tables, so the jpg-stamps overlapping text look really odd and unrealistic. The system does not support images with transparency channel either.

I'm trying to fix things by first printing reports to PDF and then manipulating images sending all them to back (below text and other vector content) using iTextSharp. Finally the results are sent to a hardware printer.

All the images are stored in resources (XObjects).

The problem is that I have no idea how to manipulate PDF-objects z-order (creation order) with iTextSharp.

The current version (a c# COM-object/assembly) works as follows:

1. Build the list of references to existing images (reference, image bytes, image CTM) in a page loop with parser.ProcessContent()
2. Execute KillIndirect() on any reference found
3. Replace them with writer.AddDirectImageSimple() and blank image (with transparent mask)
4. Insert previously stored image bytes as images (taking CTM into account) with stamper, in GetUnderContent mode.

I wonder if is there a more simple solution without blank images, excess references etc.

Comment: *I have no idea how to manipulate PDF-objects z-order* - the z-order in pdfs is given by the order in which the drawing operations appear in the respective content stream. Thus, you would have to shuffle the contents of those streams. Not trivial...

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does it mean that "my" current algorithm is then optimal or maybe there are other options to accomplish task?

Comment: It is not optimal but the alternatives are not more simple as you wondered.